# PHP variables in include not defined

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, undefined

I'm trying to get a basic registration page to work that's connected to a local database.

```
Notice: Undefined variable: dbhost in C:\wamp\www\functions.php on line 19

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\wamp\www\functions.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined variable: con in C:\wamp\www\functions.php on line 19

Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\wamp\www\functions.php on line 19
```

These are the errors I get. They occur when I reference a function in my functions.php script.

```
<?php //functions.php
$dbhost = 'localhost'; //change to webserver ip
$dbname = 'maindb';
$dbuser = 'administrator';
$dbpass = 'password';
$appname = "webapp";

$con = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass) or die (mysqli_error($con));
mysqli_select_db($con, $dbname) or die (mysqli_error($con));

function createTable($name, $query)
{
    queryMysql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $name($query)");
    echo "Table '$name' created or already exists<br>";
}

function queryMysql($query)
{
    $result = mysqli_query($dbhost, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
    return $result;
}
```

I'm not exactly sure as to what the issue here is. I learned PHP a few years ago, and it seems quite a bit has changed since 2011.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Using wrong variable in function `$dbhost`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those variables were declared in the global scope and therefore are not available to your functions. To make them so you need to pass them as parameters of that function:

```
function queryMysql($query, $con, $dbhost)
```

(You can also use the `global` keyword but that is a bad practic so I won't show it here).

Also, the first parameter of `mysqli_query()` should be your MySQL connection resource which is stored in `$con`, not`$dbhost`

```
function queryMysql($query, $con)
{
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`mysqli_query` needs the connection not the host and you have to pass it in:

```
function queryMysql($con, $query)
{
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
    return $result;
}
```

Then when you call it:

```
$result = queryMysql($con, $query)
```